# Issue with Creating Function in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am having an issue with R recognizing an argument in my function.  I am trying to take two data frames and compare the contents of a common column.  The below is my code:

```
install.packages("rowr")
library(rowr)

Check=function(zzz){
Newcheck=sqldf("select Office, Station
                           from new
                            where Office=zzz
                             group by Office, Station")   
Oldcheck=sqldf("select Office, Station
                             from old
                             where Office=zzz
                             group by Office, Station")  
check_old_v_new=cbind.fill(Newcheck,Oldcheck,fill=NA)   
return(check_old_v_new) }

Check(6)
```

Whenever I run the last line of code, I get the following message:  Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : no such column: zzz

I know zzz is not a column.  It is argument within my function. Can someone please help me identify why R is interpreting my argument as a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a variable in sqldf statement like this. Your code is considering zzz as a value in the column. You can use sprintf here.

```
install.packages("rowr")
library(rowr)

Check=function(zzz){
Newcheck=sqldf(sprintf("select Office, Station
                       from new
                        where Office='%s'
                         group by Office, Station",zzz))   

Oldcheck=sqldf(sprintf("select Office, Station
                         from old
                         where Office='%s'
                         group by Office, Station",zzz))

check_old_v_new=cbind.fill(Newcheck,Oldcheck,fill=NA)   
return(check_old_v_new) }

Check(6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a string, `"zzz"` is just 3 letters. For example, if I set the variable `i = 55`, I don't expect R to interpret `"this string"` as `"th55s str55ng"` - in fact, that would be awful.

So, if you want R to use a string stored in a variable in another string, you need to construct the string. `paste` or `sprintf` are good functions for that, for example:

```
> zzz = 6
> paste("select * from old where office =", zzz, "group by station")
[1] "select * from old where office = 6 group by station"
```

`paste` just sticks things together. `sprintf` uses a "fill-in-the-blanks" approach which can be more readable for SQL queries and the like:

```
> sprintf("select * from old where office = %s group by station", zzz)
[1] "select * from old where office = 6 group by station"
```